# Is there a way to use HCaptcha in Blazor-Server

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, hcaptcha

As the Title says, i am trying to protect my website from bots using HCaptcha. Just embedding it in the usual HTML-div- fashon doesn't seem to work. If you have any idea how this might work, please let me know!